# jQuery function show divs with display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have some jQuery code, which attempts to show the first 6 divs on page load and hide all of the others. It is littered with errors, but ideally I am trying to create a function that shows the next six divs on an event, ultimately when the user scrolls to the bottom. I know my code is not great, but I have done my best to make it as easy to follow as possible.

The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/gRzPF/4/), and any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: When you run your script in a browser and it doesn't work, you will usually get an acceptable description of what went wrong in the console. In Firefox you can open it with Ctrl+Shift+J, in IE I think it's F12. It will give you hints to things like 'unexpected , expecting ;' You will often have to scroll down and try to trigger the error again because many websites crowd the console with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/gRzPF/8/

If I understand correctly every time you get to the bottom of the window you want to show the next 6 divs. My edit achieves that.

You just needed to use semi-colons in your `for` statement, wrap a function around it and move your `constraintNumber` variable inside that function.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
for (i = contentNumber, i < constraintNumber, i++;) {
```

by

```
for (i = contentNumber; i < constraintNumber; i++) {
```

in javascript (and C), `;` must separate the 3 elements of a `for` statement

in jsfiddle, you have 'JSLint' button to verify code error !! Use it !

Comment: Ahh brilliant thanks! Its always the small things. Do you know how i could change it into a function? And call that function when the user reaches the bottom of the page (I already have this code)?

Answer (score 1):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/gRzPF/7/ I modified your code, now it seems to work :)

Comment: Perfect! Will accept imminently, one bug: when you get to the bottom of the page, everything disappears?

Comment: Don't sure that I correctly understood the problem at the first time, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gRzPF/9/